# How to check location.href is completed?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want open a window and then does something after it finishes loading, is there an easy way to do this?

my current code is something like:

```
cur_window = window.open( 'http://www.google.com' )
// does something when cur_window finishes loading
```

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to do this is if you write code in the page which is opened in the popup to tell the parent page, the `opener` object in js, that it has finished loading.

In your example, as your are loading Google, this is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're accessing pages within the [Same Origin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy)...

the "easy way" isn't as responsive as jQuery's `ready` event which can't be applied outside of the original window context:

```
cur_window.onload = function () {
  //new window has loaded
};
```

If you're trying to open `http://www.google.com/` in a new window, you wont have any access to the `window` object, and therefor have no way of knowing when the new window has loaded.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, I hadn't noticed the url of `google.com`. You need to make sure that you're following the [Same Origin Policy (SOP)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).